# Remove a set of characters using Regex including the space character doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Currently I am using a `StringBuilder` to remove a list of characters from a `string` as below

```
char[] charArray = { 
  '%', '&', '=', '?', '{', '}', '|', '<', '>', 
  ';', ':', ',', '"', '(', ')', '[', ']', '\\', 
  '/', '*', '+', ' ' };

// Remove special characters that aren't allowed

var sanitizedAddress = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var character in emailAddress.ToCharArray())
{
  if (Array.IndexOf(charArray, character) < 0)
    sanitizedAddress.Append(character);
}
```

I tried to use `Regex` for the same as follows

```
var invalidCharacters = Regex.Escape(@"%&=?{}|<>;:,\"()[]\\/*+\s");
emailAddress = Regex.Replace(emailAddress, invalidCharacters, "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using *Linq* (in order to *filter out* the unwanted characters with a help of `Where`) instead of *Regular Expressions*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// Hash set is faster on Contains operation than array - O(1) vs. O(N)
HashSet<char> toRemove = new HashSet<char>() { 
    '%', '&', '=', '?', '{', '}', '|', '<', '>', 
    ';', ':', ',', '"', '(', ')', '[', ']', '\\', 
    '/', '*', '+', ' ' };

string emailAddress = ...

string emailAddress = string.Concat(emailAddress
  .Where(c => !toRemove.Contains(c)));
```

You can add more `Where` e.g.

```
string emailAddress = string.Concat(emailAddress
  .Where(c => !toRemove.Contains(c))
  .Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c))); // get rid of white spaces as well
```

In case you insist on regular expressions you have to build the pattern, e.g.:

```
  char[] charArray = {
    '%', '&', '=', '?', '{', '}', '|', '<', '>',
    ';', ':', ',', '"', '(', ')', '[', ']', '\\',
    '/', '*', '+', ' ' };

  // Joined with | ("or" in regular expressions) all the characters (escaped!)
  string pattern = string.Join("|", charArray
    .Select(c => Regex.Escape(c.ToString())));
```

And then you can `Replace`:

```
  string emailAddress = Regex.Replace(emailAddress, pattern, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [character set](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[...]` for this:

```
var invalidCharacters = "[" + Regex.Escape(@"%&=?{}|<>;:,""()\*/+") + @"\]\[\s]";
emailAddress = Regex.Replace(emailAddress, invalidCharacters, "");
```

Some side notes:

- when using double quote in "at string", you should use `""`, not `\"`
- `\s` is alread an escaped sequence, so `Regex.Escape` will render `\\s`, which is not what you wanted
- `Regex.Escape` don't seem to escape `]` character correctly - that's why it's added separately